# Can't Iterate an Observable Collection object in an Object Which Placed In another Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, portable-class-library

*(Sorry if the title is such a hassle, I feel quite confused to entitle it.)*

I have a problem i iterating (either `for` or `foreach`) an `ObservableCollection` object in an object which placed in another `ObservableCollection`.

**THIS IS MY "OBJECT" CLASS** (in a portable class library)

```
public class NotationGroup : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<Notation> _notations;
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<Notation> Notations
    {
        get { return _notations; }
        set { _notations = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Notations"); }
    }

    ...
}
```

**AND THIS IS HOW I ACCESSED IT**

```
public class MainWindowModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<NotationGroup> _notationGroups;
    ....
    public ObservableCollection<NotationGroup> NotationGroups 
    { get { return _notationGroups; } set { _notationGroups = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("NotationGroups"); } }

    ...

    public void AddOrUpdateNote(Notes note, ModifierKeys mKeys)
    {
        if (mKeys == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            foreach (NotationGroup item in NotationGroups)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Notations.Count; i++) //ERROR 1
                {
                    if (item.Notations[i].IsSelected) //ERROR 2
                    {
                        item.Notations[i].Note = note; //ERROR 3
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (NotationGroups.Count(x => x.IsSelected) > 1)
            {
                var selectedNG = NotationGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected);

                ClearSelected();

                (selectedNG as NotationGroup).Notations[0].IsSelected = true; //ERROR 4
            }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

*(SOME CODE TRIMMED FOR CLARITY)*

These are the error messages :

**ERROR 1**

> The type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.

On ERROR 1, i've tried to use both `for` and `foreach` but it just the same.

**ERROR 2**

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

**ERROR 3**

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1'

**ERROR 4**

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1'

I've addded `System.Windows` too, but it didn't help.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are both classes in the same assembly? Which .NET framework are you targeting? (If .NET framework < 4, do you have WindowsBase in your list of project references?)

Comment: `NotationGroup` is in a class library. And both of them are .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to copy and paste these errors into any search engine to find the answers, quickly and easily. However, seeing as you pasted them here instead, I'll do *your* work for you:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1'

It *really* means exactly what it says... you can't use indexing on an `ObservableCollection`. So, where did you do that? The error even tells you where:

```
item.Notations[i].Note = note;
```

and

```
(selectedNG as NotationGroup).Notations[0].IsSelected = true;
```

The solution? had you searched online, you'd have found out that we use the `ElementAt` method to access elements using `LinQ`:

```
item.Notations.ElementAt(i).Note = note;
```

and

```
(selectedNG as NotationGroup).Notations.ElementAt(0).IsSelected = true;
```

Of course, this will still blow up if `i` is outside the range of the relevant collection. Next:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

You say that this occurred on this line, but I can't see how... this seems more like the last error:

> if (item.Notations[i].IsSelected)

You might need to just search online for that one. Finally, we have a simple reference problem:

> The type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.

Again, a very obvious and clear error... *`ObservableCollection` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `System.Windows`*. The fix? Just do what it says... add a reference of the `System.Windows` dll to your project.

Comment: The last one is already stated on my OP. "I've addded System.Windows too, but it didn't help."

Comment: That error is clear. That is the solution to that error.

Comment: Oh, It seems I just added `using System.Windows` without referencing the assembly. Thanks.